# Quantum pricing of financial derivatives (call option) in Qiskit Aqua

Tags: quantum-algorithms, programming, qiskit, quantum-computing-for-finance

In finance, a **European call** gives the buyer the right to buy some underlying asset such as a stock at some pre-determined strike price at a specific expiration date. The **Black-Scholes equation** is a fairly simple formula that can be easily written in Python for classical computing to value financial derivatives like the call option.

At the link below, IBM's cross-displinary quantum package for **Python**, **Qiskit Aqua**, seems to use qubits to price a European call option instead. Could someone give me a walk-through of what the code is doing line by line and how it compares to a classical Python code for pricing a European call? Are there any theoretical or numerical differences between classical and quantum pricing?

https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/master/qiskit/finance/components/uncertainty_problems/european_call_expected_value.py

Also, is there an article being used as the source for the above Python script? My guess is that it's this one, but not sure since I don't yet have a background in matching quantum code with quantum formulas:

*"Towards Pricing Financial Derivatives with an IBM Quantum Computer"*
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.05803.pdf

Comment: It seems that you are interested in application of quantum computers in finance. This article might be interesting for you: https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.06893 (Quantum Risk Analysis)

Comment: quantum VaR and CVaR. Thanks, i saw the video interview of Woerner the other week but didn't look at the paper yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tutorials for a lot of the Qiskit Aqua functions kept in the tutorials repository, and I think [this](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials/blob/4e76af1f26af57f3a1112318e5c611c52cf960de/qiskit/advanced/aqua/finance/simulation/european_call_option_pricing.ipynb) talks about the finance problem you are interested in.

All of these tutorials are also available on the [IBM Q Experience](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/) where you can run them in a browser.